# $f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2-2y^3$. Find all unit vectors, if any, such that $f_u(0,1)=\frac{6}{5}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I think that I understand what the question wants me to do:

> $f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2-2y^3$. Find all unit vectors, if any, such that $f_u(0,1)=\frac{6}{5}$

I worked out the partial derivatives:

$f_x(0,1)=3$

$f_y(0,1)=-6$

therefore $({^3_6})({^{u_1}_{u_2}})=\frac65$

but then I don't know how to work out $u_1$ and $u_2$?

Thank you!

Comment: $u$ is a unit vector so you get another equation $u_1^2+u_2^2=1$

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the directional derivative $f_u=\nabla f \cdot \vec{u}$ i.e. the inner product of the vector $\vec{u}=u_1\hat{x}+u_2\hat{y}$ with $\nabla f$. Since you have calculated the vector $\nabla f$, the rest of the problem is geometric. You can solve it by using algebra, i.e. solve the algebraic system 
$$
\begin{cases}
\vec{u}\cdot\nabla f=6/5\\
u_1^2+u_2^2=1
\end{cases}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$3a-6b=\frac65$$

$$a^2+b^2=1$$

$$b=\pm \sqrt{1-a^2}$$

Solve the equation

$$(a,b)=(24/25,7/25)\ or\ (-4/5,-3/5)$$